# Attempted import error: 'Component Name' is not exported from file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, apollo-client

I've been struggling to locate where the error message saying that attempted to import is coming from. I have checked everything and I cannot find where the error message is coming from. Can anyone look at my code and tell where I'm missing something?

I have tried so much from restoring to closing the code editor to review all the files that the console.log has told me to look into but still have not find why this error is happen within this files if you could help figure this out would be grateful because I'm stuck at the moment.

[image]

**This is Navbar.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import '../Assets/style/navigation.css';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client'; 
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { accessoriesQuery } from "../PagesQuery/navigation/accessories-links";
import { aboutQuery } from "../PagesQuery/navigation/about-links";
import { homeQuery } from "../PagesQuery/navigation/home-links";
import { helpQuery } from "../PagesQuery/navigation/help-links";


export default function App() {

  const { loading: logoAssetsLoading, error: logoassetsData } = useQuery(logoassetsQuery);
  
  //This is a query for the pages:

  const { loading: homeLoading, error: homeError, data: homeData } = useQuery(homeQuery);
  const { loading: eyeglassesLoading, error: eyeglassesError, data: eyeglassesData } = useQuery(eyeglassesQuery);
  const { loading: sunglassesLoading, error: sunglassesError, data: sunglassesData } = useQuery(sunglassesQuery);
  const { loading: accessoriesLoading, error: accessoriesError, data: accessoriesData } = useQuery(accessoriesQuery);
  const { loading: aboutLoading, error: aboutError, data: aboutData } = useQuery(aboutQuery);
  const { loading: helpLoading, error: helpError, data: helpData } = useQuery(helpQuery);
  
  //This is an error message:

  if (logoAssetsLoading) return <p>Loading Logo Assets...</p>;
  if (eyeglassesLoading || sunglassesLoading || accessoriesLoading || homeLoading || helpLoading || aboutLoading) return <p>Loading... this pages.</p>;
  if (eyeglassesError || sunglassesError || homeError || helpError || accessoriesError || aboutError) return <p>Error :( this page don't work.</p>;

  // Debugging step 1: Check the value of data.navigation
  //console.log(data.navigation);

  // Debugging step 2: Check the value of data
  //console.log(data);
  
  
  return (
    <div className='navigation'>
      <div className='full_width_container'>
        <div className='wrapper'>
        <Router>
          <React.Fragment>
            <nav>
                <div className='nav_groups logo'>
                    {homeData.homeLinks.map(link => (
                        <li key={link.slug}>
                          <Link to={`/${link.url}`}>
                            <img src={logoassetsData.logoAssets.url} alt='main logo'/>
                          </Link>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </div>
              
                <ul className='nav_groups nav_unorder'>
                    {accessoriesData.accessoriesLinks.map(link => (
                      <li key={link.id}>
                        <Link to={`/accessories/${link.slug}`}>
                          {link.title}
                        </Link>
                      </li>
                    ))}

                    {aboutData.aboutLinks.map(link => (
                      <li key={link.id}>
                        <Link to={`/about/${link.slug}`}>
                          {link.title}
                        </Link>
                      </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>

                <div className='nav_groups nav_three'>
                    {helpData.helpLinks.map(link => (
                      <li key={link.id}>
                        <Link to={`/help/${link.slug}`}>
                          {link.title}
                        </Link>
                      </li>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </nav>
          </React.Fragment>
        </Router>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}
```

**This is AboutQuery**

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const AboutQuery = gql`
    query aboutLinks {
        pages(
            where: {id: "clbzlfvd84iqn0bir8gxekb6m", slug: "accessories"}
            stage: PUBLISHED
            locales: en
        ) {
            id
            slug
            title
        }
    }`
;
```

**This is Accessories-Link.js**

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const AccessoriesQuery = gql`
    query accessoriesLinks {
        pages(
            where: {id: "clbzlfvd84iqn0bir8gxekb6m", slug: "accessories"}
            stage: PUBLISHED
            locales: en
        ) {
            id
            slug
            title
        }
    }`
;
```

**This is Help-Link.js**

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const HelpQuery = gql`
    query helpLinks {
        pages(
            where: {id: "clc8822bzj0rg0biqqg1it31w", slug: "help"}
            stage: PUBLISHED
            locales: en
        ) {
            id
            slug
            title
        }
    }`
;
```

**This is Home-Link.js**

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const HomeQuery = gql`
    query homeLinks {
        pages(
            where: {id: "clbzl7ovpe64d0ak5qh7o2p8f", slug: "Home"}
            stage: PUBLISHED
            locales: en
        ) {
            id
            slug
            title
        }
    }`
;
```

Comment: You've a bunch of typos, all the components are exported using ***P***ascalCase, but the components you are importing use ***c***amelCase. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Answer (score 1):

Case error, all your exports are first letter Uppercase (ex: `export const HomeQuery`) but your imports are all camelCase:

```
import { accessoriesQuery } from "../PagesQuery/navigation/accessories-links";
import { aboutQuery } from "../PagesQuery/navigation/about-links";
import { homeQuery } from "../PagesQuery/navigation/home-links";
import { helpQuery } from "../PagesQuery/navigation/help-links";
```

Comment: I'm going to try this going to change everything as lowercase folder structure but we are still getting the same error message from before `Attempted import error: 'aboutQuery' is not exported from '../pages-query/navigation/about-links'.`

Comment: The casing of the file name  or even the name of the file don't matter. The export must exactly match the import including case.

Comment: Yes I Michel I understand that clearly. When I begin to import my file I get dropdown that tells how to import my files correctly I follow the file structure of the import an I don't see why not allow to get this to work.

Comment: The error messages should guide you to the proper spelling. The other possibility is that you're getting these errors after a build and the subdirectories are not getting copied into your build folder.

Comment: I'm going to uninstall the node_modules and see if that fixed the issue.

Comment: The another thing I forgot to say is that I updated my npm to the new version. So I just remove the node_modules will check see get back with you Michel thank you   help me really do appreciate it really really much.

Comment: From there I have reinstall the node_modules that didn't do anything to fixed now I have comment out the one that making the error message happen but right now don't know what else I could do to debug this issue.

Comment: @PerceptorDev Did you fix the component export/import casing issue?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes I have fixed made everything camelCase but now still give this same error message again

Comment: Sorry I sometime I have hard time writed my coding. I had to slow down mind really looked what going on but thank you for your help.